# android popup activity show MainActivity with it

Tags: android

i use this for make floating activity

```
public class Conversation extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setUpWindow();

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}

public void setUpWindow() {
    // Nothing here because we don't need to set up anything extra for the full app.
}
}
```

this is simple activity now i will make it floating by use this

make another class

```
public class PopupConversation extends Conversation {


@Override
public void setUpWindow() {

    // Creates the layout for the window and the look of it
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);


    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.alpha = 1.0f;    // lower than one makes it more transparent
    params.dimAmount = 0f;  // set it higher if you want to dim behind the window
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);


    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    if (height > width) {
        getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .9), (int) (height * .7));
    } else {
        getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .7), (int) (height * .8));
    }
}
}
```

> now when i start the class PopupConversation it must show my `Conversation` activity as floating activity and that's what happen

but the problem its show or start MainActivity in my application behind it
see photo

it must be like this
as we see its floating outside application

[image]

now my code not floating outside application its start application and float it over the application

[image]

as we see the application start and the floating activity start over it

this is my activity in manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.PopupConversation"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FloatingWindow.Popup"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedActivity"

        >
    </activity>
```

and this is my style code

```
   <style name="Theme.FloatingWindow.Popup" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" > 
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnchanged</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/PopupAnimation</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

</style>
```

i want my activity be like first photo i want show it in every where in phone not in application

at the end i start the class from service by call this

```
        Intent window = new Intent(this, PopupConversation.class);
        window.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(window);
```

Comment: Probably due to android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK `<item name="android:clearTaskOnLaunch">true</item>`
like this ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i try it now same its start application first and show floating activity over it

Comment: Remove ` android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` then check it

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK same :/ :/ :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve it by use this when i start it

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this,  PopupConversation.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

so i just add 
    `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`